# Edit: If $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}{a_n}>0$ then there exists $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n\geq a>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

> Suppose that the $\beta=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}{a_n}>0$ where $\{a_n\}\subset(0,\infty)$ then there exists $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n\geq a>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I've always known by the definition of $\liminf$ that, for $\epsilon=\beta/2>0,$ there exists $n_0$ such that $$a_n>\beta/2,\;\;\forall\;n\geq n_0.$$

However, I can't really figure out the existence of $a>0$ such that $a_n\geq a>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Can anyone please, explain this to me? Thanks for your time!

**Note:** This statement can be found in [G. Zamani Eskandani and M. Raeisi](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11075-018-0521-3), page 12.

Comment: This is false. $\lim \inf$ only depends on the tail of the sequence whilst the conclusion depends on all the elements. For example, take a sequence $a_n$ satisfying the conclusion and consider the new sequence $(-1, a_1,a_2,a_3 \dots)$

Comment: Take $a = \min(\beta / 2, a_1, a_2, ..., a_{n_0})$, assuming all $a_n>0$.

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit. This statement can be found in [G. Zamani Eskandani  and M. Raeisi](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11075-018-0521-3), page 12.

Comment: @Rhys Steele: I made an edit. Is it still wrong?

Comment: @Clayton: I made an edit.

Comment: @lzralbu: I made an edit.

Comment: Your edit changes one place where it is insisted that $a >0$ to be $a \in \mathbb{R}$ but not all of them i.e. you still have $a_n \geq a > 0$ appearing in the conclusion. Is the thing you want to prove just that the sequence $a_n$ is bounded below?

Comment: @Rhys Steele: Thanks a lot but if you check the reference I posted, you'll see that the new edit I made, tallied with their statement. Does this mean that the paper is false?

Comment: You should be a lot more careful to include all of your hypotheses. The reason that the result is true in the paper is that their sequence takes values in $(0,\infty)$. You should also make your questions here self-contained. That paper is behind a paywall and you are reasonably lucky that someone willing to check it here also had access.

Comment: @Rhys Steele: Thank you very much! I didn't realize that before now. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the correct hypotheses this question is straightforward. You've noticed that there is an $n_0$ and an $a'$ such that $n \geq n_0$ implies that $a_n > a' >0$. Now just take $a = \min\{a_1, \dots, a_{n_0-1}, a'\}>0$.